# What is an $\infty\text{-}E_{\infty}$ morphism?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, operads, higher-algebra

My question is essentially what the title says, but here is some background that I have gathered from skimming through the literature. Please feel free to correct me if my understanding is wrong at some point.

First, the definition of an $E_\infty$-operad.

- For spaces, as considered by Peter May [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/229895), an $E_\infty$-operad is a symmetric operad $\mathcal{E} = \{\mathcal{E}(n)\}$ consists of spaces $\mathcal{E}(n)$ with a *free* action of the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$, and furthermore each $\mathcal{C}(n)$ is a contractible space.
- For chain complexes (or DGAs) over some ring $R$, an $E_\infty$-operad $\mathcal{E}$ is a symmetric operad where each $\mathcal{E}(n)$ is free over the group ring $R[\Sigma_n]$, and furthermore $\mathcal{E}(n)$ is quasi-isomorphic to $R$ (i.e, $\mathcal{E}$ is quasi-isomorphic to the operad $\mathcal{Com}$ of commutative $R$-algebras).
- In general, an $E_\infty$-operad is a $\Sigma$-free cofibrant operad, where some suitable model structure is chosen on the category of symmetric operads. In particular, the weak equivalences are given point-wise.

Now, let $\mathcal{E}$ be some fixed $E_\infty$-operad in chain complexes. Then, for two $\mathcal{E}$-algebras $A, B$, an $E_\infty$-morphism $f:A \to B$ is a chain map $f : A \to B$ satisfying the commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{E}(n)\otimes A^{\otimes^n} @>>> A\\
@V{1\otimes f^{\otimes^n}}VV @VV{f}V \\
\mathcal{E}(n)\otimes B^{\otimes^n} @>>> B
\end{CD}$$

This is the usual definition of a morphism for algebras over an operad. But in the case of, say, $A_\infty$-algebras, there is a well known notion of *weak* morphisms which satisfies many nice homtopical properties. In fact, this weak morphism is usually called an $A_\infty$-morphim in the literature (eg, section 3 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910179.pdf) by B. Keller). If we follow the definition from the article [Homotopy theory of homotopy algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5533) by Bruno Vallette (or the book Algebraic Operads by J.L. Loday and B. Vallete), this weak morphism should be called an $\infty\text{-}A_\infty$-morphism.

**Question:** Is there a suitable notion of $\infty$-morphisms for $\mathcal{E}$-algebras, where $\mathcal{E}$ is some fixed $E_\infty$-operad?

**Motivation:** The main motivation behind the question is a result of Gugenheim as proved [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-21/issue-3/On-Chens-iterated-integrals/10.1215/ijm/1256049021.full) (and interpreted in the language of $A_\infty$-algebra [here](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/2013/16/3790/728169)). It says that the Stokes' integration map $\int : \Omega^\bullet(M) \to C^\bullet(M)$ for a closed manifold $M$ can be lifted to an $\infty\text{-}A_\infty$-quasi-isomorphism, where $C^\bullet(M)$ is the complex of smooth cochains with $\mathbb{R}$-coefficients, and $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ is the deRham complex. Now, $C^\bullet(M)$ has a natural $E_\infty$-algebra structure via the surjection operad of [McLure and Smith](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106024), and $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ is trivially an $E_\infty$-algebra. The $\int$-map induces an algebra map in the cohomology, but it fails to be an algebra map at the cochain level, which implies that $\int$ cannot be lifted to a *strict* $E_\infty$-morphism. But can we hope for a lift to a *weak* $E_\infty$-morphism? Something very similar was proved [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.00669) for the Cartan-Serre map. Note that the authors are considering *strict* $E_\infty$-morphisms in the article, since the Cartan-Serre map is known to be an algebra morphism.

I would assume that an $\infty$-morphism $f:A \to B$ of $\mathcal{E}$-algebras should be given by a family of maps $$\{f_n : \mathcal{E}(n)\otimes A^{\otimes^n} \to B\}$$ satisfying some coherency conditions. Another possibility might be similar to [Gugenheim and Munkholm's DASH morphisms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404974900267): define an $\infty$-morphism $A_1 \to A_2$ between two $E_\infty$-algebras to be a strict $E_\infty$-morphism $BA_1 \to BA_2$, where $BA_i$ is the bar complex of $A_i$. The bar complex of an $E_\infty$-algebra is again an $E_\infty$-algebra as proved by B. Fresse in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601085), but I am not sure if Fresse considers such maps as I am not too familiar with the content of the article.  I have not looked into Jacob Lurie's work on Higher Algebra. If Lurie indeed considers such an $\infty$-morphism, I would be grateful if someone could point it out to me.

Assuming a suitable notion $\infty$-morphism exists, here are some properties that are desirable in my opinion.

- For $\infty\text{-}A_\infty$-morphism, it is well-known that $\infty$-quasi-isomorphisms are invertible up to homtopy. Can we expect similar statement for $\infty\text{-}E_\infty$-morphisms?
- A question about transfer of $E_\infty$-algebra structure was asked in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/414391). But I think there an "$E_\infty$-map" is just a strict $E_\infty$-morphism. Can we hope for a transfer theorem with this weaker notion of $E_\infty$-morphism?
- Given an arbitray operad $\mathcal{P}$, one can consider the operad $\mathcal{P}_\infty = \Omega B \mathcal{P}$, where $B(\_)$ is the (operadic) bar construction and $\Omega(\_)$ is the cobar construction. Following Bruno Vallette's [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5533), there is a notion of $\infty\text{-}\mathcal{P}_\infty$-morphisms in the category of $\mathcal{P}_\infty$-algebras. In particular, Vallette proves that the homotopy category of $\mathcal{P}$-algebras is equivalent to the category of $\mathcal{P}_\infty$-algebras, with $\infty\text{-}\mathcal{P}_\infty$-morphisms. Can we identify the category of $\mathcal{E}$-algebras (for a fixed $E_\infty$-operad $\mathcal{E}$) with $\infty\text{-}E_\infty$-morphisms as a homotopy category of some other category?

Any comments or references regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The point of view of $\infty$-operads defines a notion of "weak morphism": this corresponds to morphisms in the $\infty$-category of $E_\infty$-algebras. They can be seen as the cochain level through rectification results, and they allow transfer of $E_\infty$-algebra structures. This is sufficient to promote the Stokes integration map to an $E_\infty$-algebra map: for $M$ a point, this is easy, which gives the case where $M$ is an euclidian ball by transfer, and we get the general case by descent.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski As I am not very familiar with $\infty$-categories, I will repeat what I understood from the first line of your comment. Firstly, one can treat any $E_\infty$-operad $\mathcal{E}$ as an $\infty$-operad in the sense of, say, Moerdijk-Weiss. The category of $\mathcal{E}$-algebras gets an $\infty$-category structure. Then, an $\infty\text{-}E_\infty$-morphism is a 'weak morphism' in this $\infty$-category. If this is the correct interpretation, could you point me to some articles where this point of view is spelled out for $E_\infty$ or maybe even for $A_\infty$-operads?

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski As for the rest of your comment, I think I get the idea, provided I am able to decipher the notion of $\infty$-morphisms in the first place! Just one question, by descent you mean some sort of gluing of the data right? That is, we can 'glue together' the $\infty$-morphisms on different charts (=Euclidean balls) to get a full morphism on the manifold.